# Former Employer lied on 2016 1095-C form

Tags: united-states, health-insurance, employer

I was laid off work on March 5th 2015 and was provided insurance up until March 20th 2015 and then offered Cobra. My husband had a new job and his insurance started as of June 1st and we had no issues and, therefore, did not elect to pay for the cobra insurance (expensive). when we had our taxes done for 2014 we paid a penalty for three months of lag between lack of insurance. Now today (2/22/2017) I received a 2016 1095-C form that has checked Part ll on Line 14 (1G).
So this leads to my question: Why did I receive this form since I was not offered employer insurance for any part of the year of 2016?

Answer (score 10):

If I understand your question correctly, your old employer, who you haven't worked for since March 2015, sent you a 2016 1095-C. And you had health insurance all through 2016 from your husband's current employer.

If that summary is correct, I think you can safely ignore this form. Since you were covered for all of 2016 under your husband's employer's plan, you shouldn't need to pay a penalty this year on your taxes. And your husband's employer (or the insurance company) should be filing whatever IRS forms they are required to file to state that.

As to why your old employer filed the form, I'm not sure. Perhaps they filed it because you declined COBRA coverage, which can last 18 months (or more) and could have gone into 2016 if you had taken it.

Comment: It could depend on the COBRA election period given by the former employer. While the minimum is 60 days, many employers, particularly during layoffs, offer longer periods. If the former employer had offered a COBRA election period that extended into the next year, that could be why a 1095-C was created.